# Utility Guarantee of Small Data Base Mechanism in Differential Privacy

Tags: data-privacy, database, differential-privacy

I am reading Section 4.1 (An offline algorithm: SmallDB) of [*The Algorithmic Foundations of Differential Privacy* by Dwork and Roth](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Eaaroth/Papers/privacybook.pdf). I am stuck at the proof of Proposition 4.4, which is about the utility guarantee of the small database mechanism (Algorithm 4 in page 70).

> **Proposition 4.4.** Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be any class of linear queries. Let $y$ be the database output by SmallDB($x,\mathcal{Q},\epsilon,\alpha$). Then with probability $1-\beta$:
> $$
> \max_{f\in\mathcal{Q}}|f(x)-f(y)|\le\alpha+\frac{2\left(\frac{\log|\mathcal{X}|\log|\mathcal{Q}|}{\alpha^2}+\log\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)\right)}{\epsilon\|x\|_1}.
> $$
> *Proof.* Applying the utility bounds for the exponential mechanism (Theorem 3.11) with $\Delta u=\frac{1}{\|x\|_1}$ and $\text{OPT}_q(x)\le\alpha$ (which follows from Theorem 4.2), we find:
> $$
> \Pr\left[\max_{f\in\mathcal{Q}}|f(x)-f(y)|\ge\alpha+\frac{2}{\epsilon\|x\|_1}\left(\log|\mathcal{R}|+t\right)\right]\le e^{-t}.
> $$

Here $\mathcal{R}=\{y\in\mathbb{N}^{|\mathcal{X}|}:\|y\|_1=\log|\mathcal{Q}|/\alpha^2\}$ is the collection of small databases, and $u:\mathbb{N}^{|\mathcal{X}|}\times\mathcal{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$
u(x,y)=-\max_{f\in\mathcal{Q}}|f(x)-f(y)|,
$$
which measures the similarity between an arbitrary database $x$ and a small database $y\in\mathcal{R}$.

**My question:** Why is $\Delta u=1/\|x\|_1$? According to page 38, $\Delta u$ is defined by
$$
\Delta u=\max_{y\in\mathcal{R}}\max_{\|x-x'\|_1\le 1}|u(x,y)-u(x',y)|,
$$
so $\Delta u$ should not depend on the size of any database $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Proposition 4.4 states a bound for *normalized* linear queries, hence counting queries of the form

$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{||x||_1}\sum_{i=1}^{|\mathcal{X}|}x_i f(\mathcal{X}_i).$$

In this way, by using the neighboring definition of *one different user* (so the neighboring databases have the same size $||x||_1$ but they differ by one row), the utility function $u(x,y)$ takes the normalization factor in its global sensitivity from the function $f$.

$$\Delta u = \max_{y\in \mathcal{R}}\max_{||x-x'||_1\leq 1}|u(x,y)-u(x',y)| = \max_{y\in \mathcal{R}}\max_{||x-x'||_1\leq 1}\dfrac{1}{||x||_1}|\tilde{u}(x,y)-\tilde{u}(x',y)| =\dfrac{1}{||x||_1},$$

where $\tilde{u}$ is the un-normalized version of $u$, hence a counting queries with sensitivity 1.